# How to make Vlookup Macro in excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I need help to create a Vlookup macro. I'm newbie. I have 2 work sheets. Sheet 1, I copy paste from a website. It contains company name, address, telephone etc. What I want is if I hit the macro button, these info will propagate in sheet 2, filling in various columns in order that I listed the columns (ex. I want company name on A1, Telephone on B1, Contact name on C1 etc.)

So the end result is, i copy paste this info from a website to sheet 1, hit the macro and on sheet 2, I will see these info on a list form. I am doing this for my sales calls list and I found a website with company informations in it.

***Sheet 1:***

[image]

***Sheet 2:***

[image]

So I want to leave these columns blank: Contact name, role, direct phone, date & time, notes. Every other columns on sheet 2 are found in sheet 1.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just to add, my end goal is I can repeat this process by copy pasting to sheet 1, hit macro, rinse and repeat. At the end of the day, I will see on sheet 2 all the companies that I added. Thank you all appreciate the help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Are you familiar with the `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` function?

Comment: What vba code do you have so far? Have you looked for similar questions on here?

Answer (score 0):

Dear friend when you copy data from website, paste as transpose as shown in fig. Then Vlookup easily works after little tweaking

some different ways also for transpose existing data...

[image]

Comment: "past" should be "paste".